# OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, data-science, python-imageio

Getting following error while writing an image file:

```
imageio.imwrite(fname,g);
File "C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 261, in imwrite
writer.append_data(im)
....
....
raise IOError("encoder error %d when writing image file" % s)
OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file
```

function where I am writing my code is :

```
def main():
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    ....
    ....
    g = numpy.reshape(a,(len(a)//width,width));
    g = numpy.uint8(g);
    fname = str(filename + '.jpg');
    imageio.imwrite(fname,g);
```

I am beginner in this, please help.

Comment: you're writing in the current directory you aware of that? do you have the rights to write there?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and I have the rights to write there. Can you please help me in resolving this.